# Sessão é perdida após post com FileUpload - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Estou utilizando o FileUpload em uma página de cadastro de uma área logada, mas quando o post é executado minha Session é perdida.

já tentei usar UpdatePanel e não resolveu o problema. Outras soluções que tentei e também não resolveram foram: cookieless e usar sessionstate=StateServer (neste caso porque minha hospedagem não está com o serviço habilitado).

### HTML

```
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="uplImagem" CssClass="form-control-file" AllowMultiple="false" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUploadImagem" Text="Carregar" OnClick="btnUploadImagem_Click" CssClass="btn btn-outline-primary" />
```

### Código do botão

```
protected void btnUploadImagem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(uplImagem.PostedFile.FileName))
            {
                if (uplImagem.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || uplImagem.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png")
                {
                    if (uplImagem.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 512000)
                    {
                        String nomeArquivo = String.Concat("acao", hdnIdSorteio.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'), ".jpg");
                        String fullpath = String.Concat(MapPath(CaminhoUpload), nomeArquivo);
                        uplImagem.SaveAs(fullpath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ExibirMensagem("Arquivo muito grande. Tamanho máximo permitido: 500 Kb.", TipoMensagem.Alerta);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ExibirMensagem("Tipo de arquivo inválido. Tipos permitidos: JPEG, JPG e PNG.", TipoMensagem.Alerta);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ExibirMensagem("Nenhum arquivo selecionado.", TipoMensagem.Informacao);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExibirMensagem("Erro ao carregar imagem. Tente novamente.", TipoMensagem.Erro);
            Logger.GravaLog(ex);
        }
    }
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Como você fez o diagnóstico da perda de sessão? Em que momento ela é abandonada?

Comment: Identifiquei a perda de sessão pelo log da aplicação, o erro acontece onde recupero o código do usuário logado que guardo no Session. Sempre que faço o upload da imagem o problema acontece, na mesma página faço insert/update no MySql e isso funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Eu me referia em seu código, porque o apresentando, não trabalha em momento algum com sessão... mas você diz que se faz um upload pelo método acima ele abandona a sessão? Debugando, você verificou se é exatamente nesse ponto?